# Using PageView in flutter with dot indicator, on swiping every page need to change the button also just like in ninjacart app

Tags: android, flutter

Using PageView in a flutter with dot indicator, on swiping every page need to change the button also just like in NinjaCart app.

For example like page 2 button is "Next", on third-page button is" capture"

[image]

Comment: Have u checked [page_view_indicators](https://pub.dev/packages/page_view_indicators)

Comment: on swiping the pageview  want to change the button as shown in image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can know which page your `PageView` is in if you give it a controller and add a listener to that controller. Then you can have a variable that always has the current page of your `PageView` and you can change other `Widgets` based on that value:

**Declarations**

```
PageController _pageController = PageController();
double currentPage = 0;

@override
void initState() {
  _pageController.addListener((){
    setState(() {
      currentPage = _pageController.page;
    });
  });
  super.initState();
}
```

**Widget**

```
PageView(
  controller: _pageController,
  ...
),
```

Comment: Can you please share your code and what you have tried? The solution I gave you works, but you have to store that variable somewhere that makes sense and you can re-use. Either on the utmost parent state or on you State Management solution.

Comment: I got it by using global variable. Thanks

Comment: If an answer fixed your issue, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 28):

Here is a Single dot widget

```dart
 Widget _indicator(bool isActive) {
      return Container(
        height: 10,
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
          height: isActive
              ? 10:8.0,
          width: isActive
              ? 12:8.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              isActive
                  ? BoxShadow(
                color: Color(0XFF2FB7B2).withOpacity(0.72),
                blurRadius: 4.0,
                spreadRadius: 1.0,
                offset: Offset(
                  0.0,
                  0.0,
                ),
              )
                  : BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.transparent,
              )
            ],
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: isActive ? Color(0XFF6BC4C9) : Color(0XFFEAEAEA),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Build the dots group widget by length of the list view

```dart
 List<Widget> _buildPageIndicator() {
          List<Widget> list = [];
          for (int i = 0; i < YourListHere.length; i++) {
            list.add(i == selectedindex ? _indicator(true) : _indicator(false));
          }
          return list;
        }
```

PageView Widget

```dart
 PageView.builder(
     controller: _pageController,
     onPageChanged: (int page) {
         setState(() {
             selectedindex = page;
         });
     },
     itemCount: YourListHere.length,
```

[image: result]

Comment: Worked as it is! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

`TabPageSelector` is a widget with shows paging dots.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabPageSelector-class.html

Just use `TabController.index = i` to set which dot is highlighted.

Comment: PageView and TabBarView are different things